# To apply CssClass according to File extension

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have five cssclass to whom i want to apply them according to my uploaded file. If i upload Pdf then there is different class and if it is excel then different class is present accordingly. I was thinking to do switch statement but i have no clue how to do.
Below is my input file and submit button code

```
  <div class="col-md-7">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="filena" class="custom-file-input">
  </div>      
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
  <input type="submit" id="SaveBtn" value="Save" name="actionType" class="btn-class btn-success">
  <input type="submit" id="UpdateBtn" value="Update" name="actionType" class="btn-class btn-success">
     </div>
  </div>
```

And below is my css class name in which i want to apply them

```
<td><i class=""></i></td>
```

and class value for word file will be: "fa fa-file-word-o text-primary AssetIcon"
and for PDF: "fa fa-file-pdf-o text-danger AssetIcon"
Please help if any clue

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Getting the extension? The switch statement? Applying the class? All of the above?

Comment: @Turnip for switch and applying class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments that you already have the file extension I'll miss that part out:

```js
var fileExtension = 'pdf';
var classList = 'fa AssetIcon '; /* base classes */

/* Append custom classes to base classses dependant on current value of "fileExtension" */
switch(fileExtension) {
    case 'pdf':
        classList += 'fa-file-pdf-o text-primary';
        break;
    case 'doc':
        classList += 'fa-file-word-o text-danger';
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Invalid file type.')
}

/* Select target element and apply classes */
document.getElementById('target').className = classList;
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<td><i id="target" class=""></i></td>
```

If you only ever have two possible file types you could replace the switch with a one liner by using the ternary operator:

```js
var fileExtension = 'doc';
var classList = 'fa AssetIcon '; /* base classes */

/* Append custom classes to base classses dependant on current value of "fileExtension" */
classList += (fileExtension === 'pdf') ? 'fa-file-pdf-o text-primary' : 'fa-file-word-o text-danger'

/* Select target element and apply classes */
document.getElementById('target').className = classList;
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<td><i id="target" class=""></i></td>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but the thing is i'm fetching extension of file from database also and is there any method on which i can assign class accordingly whether it is txt or pdf. Extension are my first column of every row in td tag. How  can i assign class on table onload accordingly or by calling javascript onload function.